# Unseen space (Char) in Excel Sheet causes 0 (N/A) as result, how to remove it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two Excel sheet and I am using `VLOOKUP` to find a value from one of the excel sheets and insert it as new column in the second sheet. However when I try following formula I get 0 for all the rows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),0)
```

So I did some research and tried every suggestion I found online but non of them worked.

Then I thought maybe the format of the sheets aren't the same so I did use format printer but still not working. everything looks similar in the common column of both sheets except one thing.

my common column (lets call it A) in one sheet has right alignment and in the other sheet has left alignment, even after doing Format Printer it's still not changing. So, out of curiosity, I did a backspace in one cell of sheet 2 and it worked`(A=456)`. but there is no space in the cell.

So there is an unseen space, I tried Trim and Clean function, non of them worked.

So I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestion?

```
Sheet1:

 A       B
 123  3/7/2016
 456  6/9/2015
 789  3/1/2016
```

sheet2:(Note: i did backspace for 456, it has right alignment now and it's working)

```
 A       B
123   4/8/2016
 456  8/9/2016
789   3/7/2016
```

result after above formula:

```
 A        B           C
 123   3/7/2016       0
 456   6/9/2015    8/9/2016
 789   3/1/2016       0
```

Thank you

Comment: Try this `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2,FALSE ), "0")` make sure the column C to format as Date

Comment: what if non of the answers solve the problem? :)

Comment: sorry to hear that, can you share the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Sheet2 Column B is already formatted as date no need for **[DATEVALUE Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)**

*Try* ***`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE), "0")`***

> *<sub>[The DATEVALUE Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is helpful in cases where a worksheet contains dates in a text format that you want to filter, sort, or format as dates, or use in date calculations.
>   To view a date serial number as a date, you must apply a date format to the cell. Find links to more information about displaying numbers as dates in the See Also section.</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>[IFERROR Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-C526FD07-CAEB-47B8-8BB6-63F3E417F611) Returns a value you specify if a formula evaluates to an error; otherwise, returns the result of the formula. Use the IFERROR function to trap and handle errors in a formula.</sub>*

Comment: 1. Why are all of the suggestions putting the IFERROR default value of zero as `"0"` ? 2. A better 'official documentation blurb might be: '*The column number (third parameter) in the range that contains the return value. For example, if you specify B2: D11 as the range, you should count B as the first column, C as the second, and so on.*' I added **(third parameter)**.

Comment: @Jeeped `IFERROR`, I'm assuming OP wants to see `0` rather then `#N/A`. How you suggest the formula is written?

Comment: Well, a simple `0` instead of `"0"` would suffice. The latter is text-that-looks-like-a-number, not a true number.

Comment: @Jeeped correct `text` but if I use true number then it returns `1/0/1900`

Comment: Good point for a definitive date-type cell format but not for a *General* format which would show m/d/yyyy or 0 depending on the number.

Comment: thank you but it's not the solution. As I mentioned before, the issue here is the formats of Sheet1(A) and Sheet2(A) aren't similar. when I do Backspace on Sheet1(A) it works and gives me the desired result but there is no space there so i'm so confused what the problem is.